# How does one sample all images uniformly when the data set is organized in hierarchies?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, sampling, conditional-probability

I have a data set with $C=64$ classes and $N_c = 600$ images and total images $N = \sum_c N_c$. Each class has a separate folder for each class. I want to be able to sample images as if they were in a union of all folders (i.e. any image has the same probability no matter where it is located and even if classes are unbalanced). The issue is that I don't want to actually flatten the data set into a union as that duplicates the data and higher storage costs. So I want to sample such that if I were to sample a batch e.g. $B=1024$ then every image has the same chance of occurring. I think for that I need that the probability of an image to be equal to:

$$ Pr[X = x] = \frac{1}{N}$$

I think that is what my problem boils down to if I am correct (correct me if that is the wrong modeling please!)

So for that to happen I think what I need to do is first sample a class with probability equal $$Pr[C=c] = \frac{N_c C}{N}$$
and sampling an image given that class uniformly i.e. with probability
$$ Pr[X=x \mid C = c] = \frac{1}{N_c}$$

This is what I get using the marginalization rule for probs:

$$ Pr[X=x] = \sum_c p(c) p(x \mid c) = \frac{1}{N} $$

if you plug in the numbers.

But that seems weird, I would have thought that it's sufficient to simply sample any class weighted by the number of images it has and then sample a image uniformly (i.e. just sample uniformly twice $B$ times to get your batch).

But formal calculations seem to give me something else, what is my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

just create list of all files, then sample this list and voila!,

as for calculations:

probability sampling image from class $A$ sampling from whole set is $P(class\_A)=size(A)/size(whole\_set)$ but in second sampling/drawing $P(class\_A)=\frac{size(A)-1}{size(whole\_set)-1}$ because I presume you are sampling without replacement, of course after picking class/subset you can sample uniformly from this smaller set